# Passing array of dictionary objects to a query parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to pass an array of dictionaries to one of the query parameters

I tried manually appending "?" followed by name value pairs joined by "&", I got the string I need but its not working when I fire API through code, its working on postman with the same string.

This is what I'm looking for
/action.php?module=products&action=fetchTagsandProducts&tag_information=[{"tag_id":30, "tag_type":1}, {"tag_id":20, "tag_type":1}]&category_id=1&locality_id=25

Can anyone suggest how it can be done? 
That would be great if you can share an example.

Comment: Send them as a body param but do not include them in the request.

Comment: I tried posting JSON data as body parameter as well, which always gives response as null. I have no clue where it is going wrong. I have set url, method, content type, content length and body. Its neither throwing error nor response. Actually when I post it as body parameter, request is not hitting server.

Comment: before even trying in xcode, use postman plugin/app to see if you are making a valid request.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to put JSON into the query part of the request URL. That is a bad idea, and fraught with problems.

Don't do that.

Many of the characters used in JSON are reserved characters in a URL. You should reformulate your request as a POST with the JSON data as the body of the POST.

Comment: I tried posting JSON data as body parameter as well, which always gives response as null. I have no clue where it is going wrong. I have set url, method, content type, content length and body. Its neither throwing error nor response. Actually when I post it as body parameter, request is not hitting server.

Comment: The real question is what does the server expect. You can't just stuff data in random fields. You need to deliver the data in the format that the server is expecting. Check the docs on the API call you're using. I can tell you that Embedding JSON In a query  parameter is not valid